# How to force the browser to parse the MathML content again?

Tags: javascript, parsing, dynamic, browser, mathml

To be specific(MathJax is not what I am looking for)I have a web-page with some MathML in it.The "FireFox" browser parses it fine but when I try to add the same code through javascript,it doesn't parse it.How can I notify the browser to parse the content of the web page again?Even if it is in some other language than javascript
Here is the javascript code:

```
    var b=document.createElement("math");
    b.setAttribute("xmlns","http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML");
    var msup=document.createElement("msup");
    var c=document.createElement("mi");
    c.innerHTML="c";
    var p=document.createElement("mn");
    p.innerHTML="6";
    msup.appendChild(c);
    msup.appendChild(p);
    b.appendChild(msup);
    document.body.appendChild(b);
```

Here is the HTML that it generates

```
    <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <msup>
    <mi>c</mi>
    <mn>6</mn>
    </msup>
    </math>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `document.createElementNS()` rather than `document.createElement()` in order to create the element in the proper namespace. Setting the `xmlns` attribute after the fact doesn't actually do it.  So here is an example that works for me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test adding MathML</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var MML = "http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML";
var b=document.createElementNS(MML,"math");
var msup=document.createElementNS(MML,"msup");
var c=document.createElementNS(MML,"mi");
c.appendChild(document.createTextNode("c"));
var p=document.createElementNS(MML,"mn");
p.appendChild(document.createTextNode("6"));
msup.appendChild(c);
msup.appendChild(p);
b.appendChild(msup);
document.body.appendChild(b);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also switched your use of `innerHTML` to use `document.createTextNode()` for consistency with the way you are creating the other nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to force the rebuilding by setting the innerHTML of a div element :

```
myDiv.innerHTML = b.outerHTML;
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/azuwux/1/edit) (click "Run on JS")

Of course [it works only on some browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=mathm).